# Cascade parent-child with not-autogenerated id using spring boot, crud repository, hibernate and postgres

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, cascade, crud-repository

I have an issue with crudRepository (Spring boot-hibernate-postgres) and cascade when I try to save some related entities with a specific id (not autogenerated).
I spent some time googling without success.

This is the method:

```
  private String importSourceInfo() {
    SourceCompany sourceCompany= new SourceCompany();
    sourceCompany.setName("companyName");
    sourceCompany.setId(UUID.fromString("2bf05cbc-d530-11eb-b8bc-0242ac130003"));
    Set<SourceUser> sourceUsers = new HashSet<>();

    SourceUser sourceUser= new SourceUser();
    sourceUser.setName("dev-team");
    sourceUser.setId(UUID.fromString("4bede7a0-d530-11eb-b8bc-0242ac130003"));
    sourceUser.setCompany(sourceCompany);

    sourceUsers.add(sourceUser);
    sourceCompany.setUsers(sourceUsers);

    SourceInfo sourceInfo= new SourceInfo();
    sourceInfo.setSourceUser(sourceUser);
    sourceInfo.setSourceCompany(sourceCompany);
    sourceInfo.setId(UUID.fromString("74a52aa0-d530-11eb-b8bc-0242ac130003"));
    sourceInfo.setVersion("v1");
    sourceInfo.setDescription("company v1");

    sourceInfoRepository.save(sourceInfo);
    return "SourceInfo has been imported!";
}
```

and these are the models:

SourceInfo:

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Table(name = "source_info")
public class SourceInfo {

    @Id
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_source_user", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private SourceUser sourceUser;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_source_company", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private SourceCompany sourceCompany;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    private String description;

    private String version;
}
```

SourceCompany:

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Table(name = "source_company")
public class SourceCompany {
    @Id
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "company")
    private Set<SourceUser> users;

}
```

SourceUser:

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Table(name = "source_user")
public class SourceUser {
    @Id
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    //ref
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_source_company")
    private SourceCompany company;
}
```

And this is the error:

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find xxx.sp_model.sustainability.model.utils.SourceCompany with id 2bf05cbc-d530-11eb-b8bc-0242ac130003
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar!/:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar!/:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:332) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar!/:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar!/:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar!/:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar!/:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1186) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar!/:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1051) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar!/:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:697) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar!/:5.4.27.Final]
```

I think that hibernate want to update the child sourceCompany instead of saving it if new. But I don't know how to solve it.
(I need also to extend the eventual solution in a more complex structure so I need a general solution, because at principle the id of the application are autogenerated and all works, now the need is to set these IDs in the backend and so to save specific IDs.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running into a limitation of Spring Data JPA repositories not being able to detect whether to call `EntityManager.persist` vs `EntityManager.merge`. You need to call `EntityManager.persist` to make this work.